# Javascript Object get properties from lowest level

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I want to know whats the best way to simplify a object so that it only contains the properties from the lowest level of the actual object. I will explain by the following example:

**Starting Object**

```
const start = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 2,
        d: 3
    },
    e: 4,
    f:{
        g: 5
    }
}
```

**Wanted Object**

```
const wanted = {
    a: 1,
    c: 2,
    d: 3,
    e: 4, 
    g: 5
}
```

---

I generally know how to do it, but it seems very lavish for large objects. Thus, I do not want to write:

```
const simplified = {
    a: start.a,
    c: start.b.c,
    d: start.b.d,
    e: start.e,
    g: start.f.g
}
```

Apparently, destructuring an object inside another object is not possible, but it would also help if I can get the children of the parent objects easier, somehow like that:

```
const simplified = {
    a: start.a,
    //start.b.children?
    e: start.e,
    //start.f.children?
}
```

I also want to avoid to create duplicates of the variables outside the object creation with destructuring.

---

**What is the best practice for restructuring an object in such way?**

Comment: how deep can the object nest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a recursive function that will add property to your result only if the current value is not of the `object` type, and if it is then pass it to another recursive call.

```js
const start = {"a":1,"b":{"c":2,"d":3},"e":4,"f":{"g":5}}

function flatten(data) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if (typeof v === 'object') Object.assign(r, flatten(v))
    else r[k] = v
    return r
  }, {})
}

const result = flatten(start)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map either the object or the nested parts.

```js
function flat(object) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? flat(v)
            : { [k]: v }
        ));
}

console.log(flat({ a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 3 }, e: 4, f:{ g: 5 } }));
```